# Chrome исполняет js в body не дожидаясь инициализации js в head

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Добрый день

Ситуация такая: есть сайт,

jquery инициализируется в секции "head"
все зависимые от jquery плагины инициализируются в конце "body"

В Chrome, в 50% случаев (ситуация возникает не всегда, как повезёт), плагины из "body" инициализируются до окончания инициализации основного jquery, что приводит к краху js.

на других браузерах проблема не замечена.

Вопрос: что можно сделать для корректной работы js в Chrome?

Comment: что Вы называете "инициализациeй основного jquery"?

Comment: разместить jquery тоже в конце body?)

Comment: > что Вы называете "инициализациeй основного jquery"?

Comment: Под "инициализациeй основного jquery" я имею ввиду: что в "head" подключается jquery.min.js, в конце "body" подключаются плагины jquery. при этом при загрузке страницы я получаю "$ is not a function" в плагине. (эту ошибку заметил только в chrome, и chrome-образных браузерах)